# Is there a software version of a Windows Media Center Extender?

Tags: windows-media-center, media-center-extender

Looking for a Windows and/or Mac version of a Windows Media Center Extender.

Whatever happened to [SoftSled](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softsled)?

Comment: I've wanted this for quite some time. I have a 360 (my main extender), but also other PCs I would like to be able to access my recordings and live TV with.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [XBMC](http://www.xbmc.org/) and also [TVersity](http://tversity.com).

Both are streaming applications and also provide extender functionality. However they are not always auto detected. I use XBMC to stream and view streams on my Mac while I have a dedicated TVersity server for streaming to everything else.

Answer (score 0):

We use the Xbox and PS3 as Media Center Extenders.

Some people don't even play the games.

It's kind of like using Wii just to read the news.

Comment: PS3 as a Windows Media Center Extender?

Answer (score 0):

It think that [Vuze](http://www.vuze.com/devices/index.html) can access some of the content.

EDIT: Nope I got it backwards, Vuze can stream TO and xbox, not FROM it sorry.

Comment: Do you have a link?

Answer (score 0):

Something like that is built into Windows 7; the W7 systems identify each other and your extenders across the network.  Not sure how well it work though, I use media player for my media needs :)